# Images URL is getting broken at frontend in mobile view

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-images, mobile, media-images

I created custom attribute with name Product Header Info and added the following content in the text editor:
[image]

I am getting broken URL at frontend.When I am inspecting the image it is showing something broken URL.Please have a look
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue like you before. It seems the Magento failed to render the given dynamic URL, I did this to solve:

1. I use a code editor that I suspect sent different charset encoding when I copy paste it into the TinyMCE. Especially it affected special characters like quote, double quote and forward slash.
2. I try a different code editor and turn the double quote inside url property. So, it goes like this:

```
    <img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/something.jpg'}}" alt="" >
```

3. I copy paste the code then save it. The problem is solved.

However, there is a case where you need to put in your mind that you may encounter a problem in the future when you want to use picture element tag of HTML5 in the TinyMCE, so always backup the HTML code in your file.

There is one thing that I noticed in your screenshot. You may want to disable something like Grammarly plugin (Green icon in the bottom right corner) that maybe could bring disturbance.

Check also your WYSIWYG Options in **Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Content Management > WYSIWYG Editor**. Make the **Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG** option to **No**.

PS: check your extensions that could bring an effect on your img tag element (ex. Lazy Loading feature, Preloading feature, or optimization feature, etc). You might want to test with the condition when they are enabled and disabled.